# generate list of bitmaps from path for painting them on canvas is slow

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, bitmapfactory, webm

I've list of png stored on my smartphones:

image001.png, image002.png, ..., image175.png while each image is 200-250KB.

I would like to draw them on canvas. Thus I guess I need to convert them to bitmaps so I use their path: the BitmapFactory.decodeFile is slow when there are 175 images. I tried to set the inSampleSize to be 2 and still slow (takes about 4 seconds).

```
File[] files = myFolder.listFiles();

List<File> directoryListing = new ArrayList<>();
directoryListing.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < directoryListing.size(); i++) {
    String path = directoryListing.get(i).getPath();

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    opts.inSampleSize = 1;

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);

    listBitmaps.add(bmp);
}
```

Any idea how to make the listBitmap generated faster? I mean less than 1 second even.

Please consider that the first draw of the list shouldn't be fast if it's impossible but I wish the next drawings will be fast (even when I close the app and open it again)

Another thing: the pngs are extracted from webm and they have alpha. (canvas doesn't know to draw webm)

Comment: Since you aren't using the output of first `decodeFile()` call, just use the second. That should help incrementally. However, if you do the math, you are asking Android to decode a bitmap from a file in 5-6 milliseconds (175 in "less than 1 second"), and that does not seem realistic. Perhaps you need to consider a different solution, such as combining all 175 images in one, decoding that, and rendering different sections of the resulting bitmap.

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain about the combination? They are all combined in a webm file. I download this webm file and then I export all the 175 png files from it. webm is just 1MB.

Comment: In Web development, [CSS sprites](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_sprites.asp) can speed up Web page rendering. My guess is that somebody has worked out a similar solution for Android. That will not help in your case, unless you control the content that you are downloading.